# Trying to count files in a directory of a directory, but the return is wrong

Tags: php

I have an image uploading script that creates a new image and saves it to a directory. I want to count the number of images in that directory so I can add that total, plus one, to my new images name. The directory resides within a directory of public_html.

Also, I want to use a three digit numbering system so that if the number has say, only one digit than my switch adds two zeros to the front to make it a three digit number.

My PHP script:

```
<?php
$directory = "/galleries/painting_parties/" ;
$directory_list = scandir( $directory ) ;
$numb = count( $directory_list ) ;
++$numb ;
$numb .= "" ;
$numblen = strlen( $numb ) . "" ;

switch( $numblen )
   {
   case "1" : $n = "00" . $numb ; break ;
   case "2" : $n = "0" . $numb ; break ;
   case "3" :
   default : $n = $numb ;
   }

$new_image_name = $directory . "marias_art_" . $n . "_new_image.jpg" ;
?>
```

Comment: For some reason I keep getting a return value of "002".

Comment: ...there are about 36 files in the directory so I should get a count of 36, my number should look like "036".

Comment: are you counting dots `.` `..` as files?  you should count only files ending in the extension you want.

Comment: No, I am not counting dots.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I will try count .jpg files since that is the only files I upload.

Comment: Whats all this `$numb .= "" ; $numblen = strlen( $numb ) . "" ;` supposed to do. You have a number in `$numb`

Comment: Use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php), for example: `str_pad(36, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) == '036'`, `str_pad(36, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) === '00036'`, `str_pad(4444, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) === '4444'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly As stated I want to add zeros to create a three digit numbering system.

Comment: @Gerard Roche I am trying to use simple methods. Your answer seems a bit excessive and complicated. You have not explained what these functions do.

Comment: I just realized my zeros will add to the number not as a string but as a number. This would explain why I am getting the number 2 without zeros. This still doesn't explain why I am not getting the real count of files in the directory, which is 36.

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind, that is why I turned $numb into a string first.

Comment: Now I am really confused because I am not getting my zeros either.

Comment: The code I posted should be simpler than your code. It's a one liner. I posted three examples. And a link to the manual page for the function. Your code will essentially look something like: `$new_image_name = $directory . "marias_art_" . str_pad(count($directory_list), 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "_new_image.jpg" ;` Read the manual page on the function and understand what it does.

Comment: I just realized I am not getting my zeros because the switch is defaulting.

Comment: @Gerard Roche I want to use the `scandir()` function and there should be no reason why I can not.

Comment: @Xavier Didn't say you couldn't use `scandir()`.

Comment: @Gerard Roche The `str_pad()` is for strings. My problem is the `count()` function is returning 2 when it should return 36. My problem with the zeros is solved now. I really want my question to be focused on the `count()` function.

Comment: Why does the `count()` function return 2?

Comment: Even when I remove all of the code that converts the number, I still get a return of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the directory is the issue try without the leading slash like this, as the leading slash says go to the root directory and then up from there

```
$directory = "galleries/painting_parties/" ;
```

Looks like quite a bit of unnecessary code as well

Try

```
<?php
$directory = "/galleries/painting_parties/" ;
$directory_list = scandir( $directory ) ;
$numb = count( $directory_list ) ;
// maybe subtract 2 for the . and .. directories, up to you
// $numb -= 2;
// make it a 4 char num with leading zeros
$n = sprintf('%04d', ++$numb);
$new_image_name = $directory . "marias_art_" . $n . "_new_image.jpg" ;
?>
```

Comment: Regardless of the extra code, I tried just returning the `$numb` variable on its own and still I get the number `2`.

Comment: Either way this code gives me the number 1. Then it gets incremented to 2.

Comment: The directory has 36 images.

Comment: I keep getting a return of 1.

Comment: I thought that maybe my directory is not needing that slash at the end but that did not work either.

Comment: See suggestion for an amendment to the directory

Comment: That worked! It was the leading slash the whole time!

Comment: I would like to give you the answer but your original answer was not it.

Comment: Okay I will check it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!